# org-shift[up/right/left/down] gives error on Org Clock Table pattern `yyyy-mm-dd`

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-table, org-clock, org-clock-table

I am having an issue viewing my time logged for individual days. I want to easily traverse through each day, and view the Org Clock Table for that day. When my pointer is on the clock table's config row that starts with `#+BEGIN`, I can easily traverse through each week using org-shift[up/down/left/right]. For example, with my pointer on the line `#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope tree :maxlevel 4 :block 2016-W01 :step day :link`, I can press `S-right` to traverse to the next week by changing the `:block 2016-W01` to `:block 2016-W02`, which updates my org clock for that week.

But org-shift does not work on the date pattern when it is defined for a specific day. For example, on the second Org Clock Table in my example below, I changed `2016-W01` to `2016-01-05`, in an effort to traverse each day instead of each week. But now, org-shift[up/down/left/right] does not work. I want to easily move through my timesheet and traverse `2016-01-06`, `2016-01-07`, etc. but org-shift gives me the error: `org-clocktable-shift: Wrong type argument: integerp, nil`.

```
* tasks

#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope tree :maxlevel 4 :block 2016-W01 :step day :link

Daily report: [2016-01-04 Mon]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |
#+END

#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope tree :maxlevel 4 :block 2016-01-05 :step day :link

Daily report: [2016-01-05 Tue]
| Headline          | Time   |      |      |      |
|-------------------+--------+------+------+------|
| *Total time*      | *1:20* |      |      |      |
|-------------------+--------+------+------+------|
| [[file:nil::tasks][tasks]]             | 1:20   |      |      |      |
| \_  [[file:nil::Community][Community]]     |        | 1:20 |      |      |
| \_    [[file:nil::Contractors][Contractors]] |        |      | 1:20 |      |
| \_      [[file:nil::more%20work][more work]] |        |      |      | 1:20 |
#+END

** Community
*** Contributors
**** getting work done
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2016-01-06 Wed 19:30]--[2016-01-06 Wed 21:30] =>  2:00
:END:

*** Contractors
**** more work
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2016-01-08 Fri 19:38]--[2016-01-08 Fri 21:38] =>  2:00
CLOCK: [2016-01-05 Tue 16:10]--[2016-01-05 Tue 17:30] =>  1:20
:END:
```

I investigated a little further, and I found that org-shift[up/down/left/right] works when I use the form `[2016-01-06 Wed]` for my `:block` (ie using the line `#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope tree :maxlevel 4 :block [2016-01-05 Tue] :step day :link` for my table below), but the Org Clock Table does not recognize that format. Is there a fix for this issue? Are others experiencing this same issue? Should I file a bug?

Or, is there an easier way to traverse daily Org Clock Table reports, via `:step day`?